# Returning values from single column with mysql queries

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a php function that will get a list of name from column in `users` database. What I want to do is to get all the values from the column `name` and insert it into an array.

What I've done from the php side is :

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
include ('../Core/Initialization.php');

$courseName = $_POST['courseName'];
$semester = $_POST['semester'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT `name` FROM `users` WHERE `programme` = '$courseName' AND `semester` = '$semester'") or trigger_error(mysql_error().$sql);
$column = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

$arr = array();
foreach($column as $value) {
$arr[] = array('name' => $value['name']); //I have tried it this way but it didn't work when I try to display the values.
}

echo json_encode($arr);//I have tried to remove the array and just json_encode($column). I have successfully print out the first values, but fail to print out the next values collected from the column.
```

The js function that will process/print out the name:

```
function nameProcess(data) {
alert(data.name); //This will only display the full values from the first(?) index

nameArray = data.name;

for (var i=0; i < nameArray.length; i++) {
alert(nameArray[i]);  //But, this loop only displays one character each time of the alert. Example: Each character from the word "Hello" will show up one by one as alert.
}
    }

});
```

Is there any better way to do this? What I want to do is, exporting all values from column `name` into an array, and iterate each of its value as an option of a a select box. But for now, how do I fix the problem?

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Answer (score 0):

> First of all, don't use mysql_* functions as they are deprecated and
>   removed totally PHP 7.

Back to your question, you can fetch mysql multi-dimensional array with MySQL only with loop.

Corrected code:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT `name` FROM `users` WHERE `programme` = '$courseName' AND `semester` = '$semester'") or trigger_error(mysql_error().$sql);
$res = mysql_query($sql); // Missing this.
$column = ;
$arr = array();
while ($value = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
 $arr[] = $value['name'];
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: I have updated the php with your code. But it seems that the `alert(data.name)` and `alert(nameArray[i])` are not showing any alerts/popup anymore?

Answer (score 0):

> *Note: The PHP MySQL commands you are using are deprecated. It's recommended to use the [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) class (as MySQLi is also deprecated).*

It depends on the pre-processing you are performing, but from what I can see based on the information you provided, you are passing each element of the returned data through to `nameProcess`.

So a return data of

```
array(
    array('name' => 'John Smith',
    array('name' => 'Jane Doe',
    array('name' => 'Foo Bar'
);
```

Will require the `nameProcess` function to be invoked 3 times.

So each time you go through to define

```
nameArray = data.name;
```

`nameArray` becomes a string since data.name is 'John Smith' the first invoke, 'Jane Doe' the second invoke, and 'Foo Bar' the last invoke.

So when you call

```
alert(nameArray[i]);
```

It's calling the character at position i within the string.

```
nameArray[0]; // 'J'
nameArray[1]; // 'o'
nameArray[2]; // 'h'
nameArray[3]; // 'n'
// etc
```

If you change it to:

```
function nameProcess(data) {
    alert(data.name);
    nameArray = data.name;
    alert(nameArray);
}
```

It will alert the full name.

The way around this would be to ensure that you pass the JSON parsed data to the function without the pre-processing, in which case your original code should work if you change it to:

```
function nameProcess(data) {
    alert(data.name);

    nameArray = data.name;

    for (var i=0; i < nameArray.length; i++) {
        alert(nameArray[i].name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your detailed explanation. I have changed the function code with yours. But now instead of it looping the character one by one, it's now showing "undefined" each time of the looping. But if I remove the `.name` from `alert(nameArray[i].name);`, it will show the character back one by one. ugh

Comment: Can you provide an example of `data` when it's passed to `nameProcess`? It sounds like you are still passing one array item at a time so `data.name` is a string.